# MySQL if previous row value is greater than current row value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns: date (date) and value(int).  How can I write a query to output the date and either 'Up', 'Down', or 'Same' by comparing the previous date's value to the current date's value.  (e.g. if 12/01/2016 has a value of 100 and 12/02/2016 has a value of 200 then the output should be 12/02/2016 Up.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-tips/mysql-compare-calculate-difference-successive-rows/ See this page. Nice tutorial exactly as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for here is the SQL `LAG()` function. This will allow you to retrieve the previous entry for `value`, and compare to the current entry.

Using `CASE`, you can then assign "Up", "Down" or "Same", based on the comparison result:

```
SELECT date,
    CASE 
        WHEN value > LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY date) THEN 'Up'
        WHEN value < LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY date) THEN 'Down'
        ELSE 'Same'
    END AS change
FROM 
    table_name;
```